# 301 Redirect isn't working on my website

Tags: .htaccess

I have been having a look around the net and this website trying to find answer to my problem, but cant solve it yet. So hopefully, you guys can help.

I currently have a 301 redirect on my website

```
     RewriteEngine on
     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html
     RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.teach-this.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Basically, the problem is my website is showing duplicate content.

www.teach-this.com
www.teach-this.com/index.html

I'm trying to get the redirect to work and have tried various different 301 redirects. When I type in the web address, it comes up as .com. but as soon as I click on anything within the site and go back to the homepage it comes back as com/index.html.

Any ideas would be welcome, if you need more information let me know. Or if someone can take a look at the site and tell me whats wrong that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: `%{THE_REQUEST}` will return the first line of the request, something like `GET`, `POST`, `HEAD`, etc... probably not what you are looking for, so your `RewriteRule` is never executing.

Comment: Can you post an example of a URL and the URL you would like it to redirect to?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Rewrite rules to hide `index.html` from URL, just have these lines in your `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Stil if you want to handle it via mod_rewrite then enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+/|)index\.html$ http://www.teach-this.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```